# PInvoke byte array to char not behaving properly in 64 bit

Tags: c#, char, byte, pinvoke, marshalling

I am calling C++ code from C# passing through a byte array as a parameter. This C++ code does geometry collisions and when I compile everything in 32 bit it behaves properly. when I compile everything in 64 bit, I get sporadic behavior that is sometimes correct and sometimes incorrect.

C# side:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\FullPath\CppCode.dll", EntryPoint = "GeomCompare")]
private static extern bool GeomCompare(byte[] data1, byte[] data2);
```

C++ side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
bool CppClass::GeomCompare(unsigned char *data1, unsigned char *data2)
```

In 64 bit, sometimes, when I pass through the same byte[] from the C# code on different occasions (on the c# side that byte[] is always in the same state) it is occasionally seen from the C++ as null and sometimes it reads it just fine. Other times, when reading from the byte[] the C++ gets an AccessViolationException.

The strange thing is when I compile this DLL in 32 bit, it works just fine. I'm suspecting there might be something weird with marshalling in 64 bit but I haven't found anything.

Edit:
After some testing of a dummy function using 4 integers, I found out that my parameters were all offset in memory by 32 bits when it got to the C++ side.

Example:

```
C# : |Parameter 1|Parameter 2|Parameter 3|Parameter 4|
           |           |           |           |           |
           V           V           V           V           V
C++:             |Parameter 1|Parameter 2|Parameter 3|Parameter 4|
```

It appeared that all data was shifted down 32 bits so that instead receiving parameters 1,2,3,4,  the C++ received parameters 2,3,4,garbage.

I have worked around this by passing in a garbage integer in front of the rest of my parameters on the C# side without changing the C++ code to correct this 32 bit offset. This now works when called from C# code.

However, in my final utilization, I have to call this C# code from a CLR integrated function from SQL. With or without this workaround, Im getting AccessViolationExceptions from the SQL.

Comment: Maybe the calling convention? I don't remember exactly, but shouldn't it be stdcall on both sides?

Comment: It seems the byte array are strings, if so you could try with StringBuilder class instead

Comment: The P/Invoke signature looks fine. I'd imagine that the problem is in the C++ code. Have you tried invoking the C++ from C++ in 64-bit mode?

Comment: What if you specifiy the c# as: `private static extern bool GeomCompare(IntPtr data1, IntPtr data2);` and use before you pass the byte pointer this: `fixed(byte* data1ptr = data1) fixed(byte* data2ptr = data2) GeomCompare(data1ptr, data2ptr);` Could it be c# moves the buffer arround within your call?

Comment: 1. You did not specify the right calling convention. The C++ function is `cdecl` or perhaps `thiscall`. 2. That looks like an instance method. Is it? 3. Would it be too much to ask for an SSCCE?

Comment: David Hefferman: Yes, I believe this is an instance method. However, this has been working perfectly when calling it in 32 bit mode with at 32 bit dll. It only fails in 64 bit.

Comment: I did another test, using the same pinvoke decorators, but using a simple function that adds two int parameters (int a, int b). However, when it gets to the C++ side, the parameter a has the value of the b from the C# side and parameter b is garbage data.